# Qt: Connect Signal QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged to Slot:

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I want to connect this signal https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged to my class. It is defined in qabstractitemmodel.h (QT own):

```
Q_SIGNALS:
void dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const QModelIndex &bottomRight, const QVector<int> &roles = QVector<int>());
```

and emitted in my implementation of qabstractitemmodel:

```
bool Main::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role){
if ( !index.isValid() || index.column() != 1 )
    return false;
...
emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int>( Qt::ItemDataRole::DisplayRole ));
return true;
}
```

I want to connect the signal so this slot:

```
void setProperty(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight, const QVector<int> &roles= QVector<int>());
```

(I copied parameters in hope this is saftiest solution)

and tried different connection methods

```
connect( _container->_model, SIGNAL(dataChanged () ), this, SLOT(setProperty()) );

connect( _container->_model, SIGNAL(dataChanged (const QModelIndex &, const QModelIndex &, const QVector<int> & )), this, SLOT(setProperty(const QModelIndex &, const QModelIndex &, const QVector<int> & )));
```

but I always got error: No such signal.

Comment: Are you really sure the second one does not work. Apart from this you should use the new signal/slot syntax to get the check if the connect parameters match during compiler time (see e.g. [here](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax))

Comment: Unfortunately yes

Comment: Which Qt version is this? As cherlic says, try the new syntax. Also note that QVector<int>(int n) creates a vector of size n, and not a vector with one value n! What you want is `{Qt::DispkayRole}`.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the entire error message(s) verbatim (it should probably include the signal name).  Also show the declaration of `_container->_model` -- are you sure it's a valid pointer to a `QAbstractItemModel`?  And as others have commented switching to the new Qt5 signal/slot syntax could provide a lot of useful information to help debug this.